# Database is read-only for .MDF on IIS Asp.Net Sql server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7, permissions, mdf

I get this error when I'm trying to write on my DB, he website is under wwwroot and I think I gave it the read/write permission, how can I fix it? how can I check how it's set in IIS Manager (inetmgr)? 
this is the error

```
Failed to update database "C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\FINAL4\APP_DATA\EXPERTIESE.MDF" because the database is read-only.
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

---

it's solved ,   fixed it my setting the permission for App_Data folder

Comment: "and I think I gave it the read/write permission" - how about being certain!

Comment: yep , you are right, I set the wrong permission, I fixed it my setting the permission for App_Data folder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have actually set the correct permissions on the folder!